# Multi Add To Cart, or maybe I should try something else?

Tags: cartthrob

I need a way to handle customizing a variety pack of items.  Each item is already in the inventory, but I need to set it up to where you can pick up to 3 of the different items, but no more than 2 of one certain item.  This "variety pack" will have a set price, even though the other items have different prices.

What would be the best approach?  Is there a way to dynamically generate a bundle or package?

I've been looking at on the fly and setting the price, but someone could abuse that easily once they got to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm with Vector Media Group; we make CartThrob.)

How comfortable are you with PHP? You could do this pretty easily with a custom extension that runs when an item is added to the cart and during checkout. This would enforce the quantity constraints and set the custom price.

Another way to approach this is that the person isn't adding those products to the cart at all, but instead is just adding your bundle/package item and then choosing the items as options, so their price wouldn't matter. Again you could use some custom logic to enforce the quantity constraints.

[Let us know if you want any other help with this](https://www.cartthrob.com/support/index.php?pg=request)!